# Unable to write aggregated output in spark structured streaming

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have just started with spark structured streaming, so just trying some hand's on. while aggregating my data; i am not able to write it as csv files.
I have tried below different combinations, but yet not achived the write operation.

my sample data is

```
colum,values
A,12
A,233
B,232
A,67
B,5
A,89
A,100
```

reading as streaming dataframe

```
userSchema = StructType([
     StructField("colum", StringType()),
    StructField("values", IntegerType())
])

line2 = spark \
.readStream \
.format('csv')\
.schema(userSchema)\
 .csv("/data/location")
```

I am doing following aggragation computation

```
 save=line2.groupBy("colum").count()
```

The expected output is

```
+-----+-----+
|colum|count|
+-----+-----+
|B    |2    |
|A    |5    |
|colum|1    |
+-----+-----+
```

### Scenario 1:

```
 save.writeStream.format("csv").queryName("a").outputMode("append").option("path", "/xyz/saveloc").option("checkpointLocation", "/xyz/chkptloc").start()
```

Error: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;

Remark : there is not possibility of adding watermark as there is not timestamp in data.

### Scenario 2:

```
save.writeStream.format("csv").queryName("a").outputMode("complete").option("path", "/xyz/saveloc").option("checkpointLocation", "/xyz/chkptloc").start()
```

Error: : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Data source csv does not support Complete output mode;

### Scenario 3:

```
save.writeStream.format("csv").queryName("a").outputMode("update").option("path", "/xyz/saveloc").option("checkpointLocation", "/xyz/chkptloc").start()
```

error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Data source csv does not support Update output mode;

### Scenario 4:

```
save.writeStream.format("parquet").queryName("a").outputMode("update").option("path", "/xyz/saveloc").option("checkpointLocation", "/xyz/chkptloc"").start()
```

error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Data source parquet does not support Update output mode;

### Scenario 5:

```
save.writeStream.format("console").queryName("a").outputMode("complete").option("path", "/xyz/saveloc").option("checkpointLocation", "/xyz/chkptloc"").start()
```

comment: no output generated at location.

### Scenario 6:

```
save.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("a").outputMode("complete").option("path", "/xyz/saveloc").option("checkpointLocation", "/xyz/chkptloc"").start()
```

comment : no output generated.

### Scenario 7:

```
save.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("a").outputMode("update").option("path", "/xyz/saveloc").option("checkpointLocation", "/xyz/chkptloc"").start()
```

comment : no output generated.

Please suggest me the appropriate configuration.

Comment: What are you trying to compute using this streaming query?

Comment: Hi Jacek, I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: Why are you using Structured Streaming for such a simple case like computing aggregation over a single CSV file?

Comment: this is a toy example. in my usecase, I would be doing lots of aggregation and would save it in real time for further downstream pipeline. so just checking feasibility

Comment: were you able to achieve it? I would suggest post answer so, that users who face similar issues can find it useful.

Comment: I know this comment is almost a year late. @bioinformatician , streaming will always have a timestamp so you can set the checkpoint. The stream data comes with the processing timestamp.